# .NET Create a program that collects and exports OData service data

Tags: c#, .net, odata

I am new to .NET and OData. I have task where I have given URL with OData service and I need to create program which reads OData and returns JSON file with data. I also need to have filters, limits and ordering by multiple properties. Can someone guide me to some tutorial where I could learn how to do that?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/